# Discord.js cannot send an empty message

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i've been trying to send my discord embed for a while now. But it wont send, it always errors. The error looks like this

```
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\me\Documents\npm-test\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\me\Documents\npm-

test\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/808286362100564002/messages',
  code: 50006,
  httpStatus: 400
}
```

But if i try to `console.log` the MessageEmbed object i get this

```
MessageEmbed {
  type: 'rich',
  title: 'What a cool embed',
  description: 'It has a descriptionfalse',
  url: null,
  color: 15417396,
  timestamp: 1617041078103,
  fields: [],
  thumbnail: null,
  image: null,
  video: null,
  author: null,
  provider: null,
  footer: { text: 'Even a footer', iconURL: undefined },
  files: []
}
```

I dont know what the cause of this problem is, i've tried to follow other peoples solution on here, but nothing works ):

**My custom class**

```
constructor(question: string,type: "number" | "string", optional: boolean, timeout?: number,description?: string,url?: string,color?: string | number | [number, number, number],timestamp?: Date,footer?: string){
        this.question = question;
        this.type = type;
        this.optional = optional;
        this.timeout = timeout;
        this.description = description;
        this.url = url;
        this.color = color;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.footer = footer;
    }

getEmbed(): MessageEmbed{
    const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
    Embed.setTitle(this.question)
    if(this.description) {Embed.setDescription(this.description + this.optional)}
    if(this.url) {Embed.setURL(this.url)}
    if(this.color) {Embed.setColor(this.color)}
    if(this.timestamp) {Embed.setTimestamp(this.timestamp)}
    if(this.footer) {Embed.setFooter(this.footer)}
    return Embed
}
```

**Client Code**

```
let question = new PromptQuestion("What a cool embed", "number", false, 20,"It has a description",null,[235, 64, 52],Date.now(),"Even a footer")
let embed = question.getEmbed()
console.log(embed)

client.on("message", m => {
    if(m.author.bot) { return }
    m.reply(embed)
})
```

Comment: Can you add some of your relevant code too?

Comment: Sure, most of it is in a custom class, but i will add the necesairy stuff

Comment: Weird, if I pop that in a `PromptQuestion` class, it works fine for me: https://imgur.com/a/vXDxWU2

Comment: Yeah, when i send a message embed that i made manually it works too. But with the class it doesn't work, do you think i has to do with typescript

Comment: I made it with `let question = new PromptQuestion` and `let embed = question.getEmbed()`, although I removed the flow syntax.

Comment: its just wierd, because it gets the embed correctly, as seen in the second code snippet, but it doesn't send it properly. Also when i do `embed instanceof Discord.MessageEmbed` i get `false` maybe that has something to do with it

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, or at least a fix.
instead of returning the `embed` return `new MessageEmbed(embed)`

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue turned out to be that I don't have permissions in the channel! The permissions were related to embeds/external content, so Discord probably did silently remove the embed due to the missing permissions, and then errored due to the empty message. I got a hint that it was permissions after some combination of messages flashed the missing permissions error finally.

TL;DR: check your permissions, our channel had everything besides sending messages on deny, and it wasn't a good idea.

If uncertain, try in a different channel or send the message in PM (like `msg.author.send`)